# Getting horizontal scroll bar when everything is contained in the divs

Tags: css, responsive-design, scrollbar, overflow

So basically upon resizing browser to smallest possible im still getting horizontal scroll bar for some reason. I cant have this for responsive purposes.
Any ideas?

http://www.techagesite.com/page-1work11122.htm

Another thing while im here

You will notice a email form and another div beside it with a border on it. When the browser shrinks the 2 divs collide and overlap.

Im still learning css and have tried sever approaches but nothing sticks.

Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Just add `overflow:hidden;` to whatever container is holding everything.  I just inspected element real quick in Chrome and added `*{overflow:hidden;}` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The horizontal scroll bar is appearing because `<ins class="adsbygoogle">` in the div `#box6` has an inline width specified to `200px`. To remove the horizontal scroll use the below css

```
#box6{
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

**EDIT**: To get the desired effect as mentioned in the comment try the below css in media query for smaller screen.

The MailChimp form has `width` of `200px` specified for its forms. This causes the right column to overlap the left section on re-sizing the window. So by setting width to the `div container` within the `box6` and floating to left both the left and right `div`s will push the right section below when the screen doesn't have space to occupy both the `div`s side by side.

Also `<ins class="adsbygoogle">` has a width of 200px given inline, so you can remove the `width:45%` specified for `.right-column` from your style sheet because this `div` will take the `200px width` of its content.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) and (min-width: 321px){
  #box6 .container{
    width:200px;
    float:left;
  }

  #box6 .right-column{
    float:left;
  }
}
```

Comment: how will that cause the ad to act once ive added overflow hidden?

Comment: i added it but nothing changed

Comment: I checked you website by when i inspect element, i don't see the `overflow:hidden` applied to box6

Comment: Well i checked now and it looks like the `overflow:hidden` is being applied. This might solve your problem with the scroll bar. But i think when you add the ads, it might cut off when it is beyond the container width. To prevent the ads from cutting off, i suggest to make few changes in your media queries for smaller screen.`.right-column{clear:both;float:right; // change this to float left }`. You can try this but i am not sure how this will work

Comment: well the divs there are overlapping and are meant to go underneath each other on browser resize. do you know why it isnt happening?

Comment: you have to clear the floats. Apply the `clear:both` to `.right-column`

Comment: worked. Why is right column sitting below to the right of left column and not next to?

Comment: when you give `clear:both` to the right column, it moves to position after the left column, ie it clears the float. And since there is a float:right for the right column it moves to the right side

Comment: how would i accomplish what i need to do then?

Comment: So you want both the left and right divs to stay next to each other even on small screens? Or on small screens the right-column div to go below the left div?

Comment: next to each other on bigger screens to under each other on smaller. something i could easily do with them in a container div but this email subscribe form thing messes that up because its got a few divs of its own

Comment: @Techagesite Sorry i was unable to reply sooner. Since i can't make a long comment i have updated the answer. Please check and let me know if it helps you

Comment: unless ive been fiddling with code while waiting for your reply and have changed something and forgot id say its not working. `code`.container3 {
width: 100%;

}
.left-column3 {
width: 50%;
float:left;
}
.right-column3 {
width:45%;
clear:both;float:left;
}`code`

Comment: i didnt see your edit there sorry. what sort of compatibility would using this media query have?

Comment: I am always good to help. I see that you have made some edits to your css in the site. The media queries i mentioned in the answer is for iPhone.

Comment: :) yeah i made the changes but its still not working. So i have to get them next to each other for big screens. How should i do that?

Comment: Ok fine. Lets try once again from beginning. First in your style `.right-column3{width: 45%; clear: both; float: left};` remove the clear both, and change the float left to right. Now try resizing the browser and check when are you having trouble with the alignment. After that we will go to next step

Comment: Does it look fine for you in desktop? If not just let me know how you want it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50712/discussion-between-james-and-techagesite)

Comment: @Techagesite i was off for few days, lets continue in chat